# React package, invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-hooks

I'm trying to write a NPM package with some `React` stuff included, at the moment it's just a component and a hook. To build the package I'm using Webpack. I've added `react` and `react-dom` to the externals section to ensure that it's not included in the bundle. I've also marked `react` as a `peerDependency` in the `package.json` and included it as a `devDependency`. Still I'm getting the error `Invalid hook call` when trying to use the bundle in another project. I think I've tried everything that I can Google my way to (like using the [package](https://github.com/mchalapuk/webpack-external-react) with the purpose to solve this) with no luck.

My Webpack config looks like this at the moment:

```js
const path = require('path');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV?.toLowerCase() === 'production';

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  plugins: [],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(tsx?)$/i,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.graphql', '.json'],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
  },
};

module.exports = () => {
  if (isProduction) {
    config.mode = 'production';
  } else {
    config.mode = 'development';
  }
  return config;
};
```

The essentials from `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  ...
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    ...
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  ...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.0 || ^17.0.2"
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "react": {
      "optional": true
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.19",
    "apollo-server-errors": "^2.5.0",
    "joi": "^17.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    ...
  }
}
```

The hook is very simple, it's just trying to a context created by the component using `useContext`, to be sure that there isn't an issue with this logic I've tried to just use `setState` with the same result. The hook looks somewhat like this:

```js
function useClient(): Client {
  return useContext(getContext());
}
```

`getContext` is just a function which either creates or re-uses a existing `React.Context` (heavily inspired by Apollo Client):

```js
const cache = new (canUseWeakMap ? WeakMap : Map)<
  typeof createContext,
  Context<Client | undefined>
>();

function getContext() {
  let context = cache.get(createContext);

  if (!context) {
    context = createContext<Client | undefined>(undefined);
    context.displayName = 'ClientContext';
    cache.set(createContext, context);
  }

  return context;
}

export default getContext;
```

The component where I'm trying to use the hook is a simple functional component:

```js
const HelloWorld: FC<HelloWorldProps> = () => {
  const client = useClient();

  return (
    <div>Hello World!</div>
  );
};
```

What am I missing? Really appreciate the help!

---

EDIT:

I reproduced the issue in a small sample app with just the basics, a external package using `setState` and then using that package in a `create-react-app` with the same result:

https://github.com/ganhammar/invalid-hook-call

Comment: Are you trying it locally using symlinks?

Comment: @PrayagChoraria I've tried both installing the package from file, `"my-package": "file:../Client"`, and publishing the package to GitHub packages and installing it from there, always with the same result..

Comment: What's the version of `react` and `react-dom` in your main project?

Comment: It's ´17.0.2´ for both packages in both projects, ´Client´ and main.

Comment: please post contents of `getContext`

Comment: @Gandzal Sure, added it to the question, as mentioned, it's heavily inspired by Apollo Client, https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/cbcf951256b22553bdb065dfa0d32c0a4ca804d3/src/react/context/ApolloContext.ts

Comment: Use `development` mode, and then check the output of your `webpack` build (usually in the `dist` folder). Can you verify that the contents of the file have bundled your component (and externalized `react`) correctly?

Comment: @Domi Yes, I believe that the bundled output is properly externalized, but I guess I'm not 100% about this. I created a small sample to reproduce the problem with a simpler setup, in the built output of that I see `const t=require("react"),o=()=>(0,t.useState)("external package");` in the bundled file without any other `react` references.

Comment: That is odd. As an `exported` function `useExternal` should not get its name mangled. The function `o` is not a valid hook, because it does not have the `use` name prefix. Also, in `development` mode, Webpack is not supposed to mangle names at all. Doubly odd. Make sure that (i) it is actually `mode: development`. In `production` mode (ii) disable name mangling by providing the `TerserPlugin` manually with `keep_fnames: true` - see https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#terseroptions . Also, make sure that (iii) your function is actually exported in your output file.

Comment: @Domi Thanks, I will look into this! The output was from production mode, not development, so you're right about that. The build output in development looks like the link below and with that result I get a different error: `TypeError: __webpack_modules__[moduleId] is not a function`
https://gist.github.com/ganhammar/b82724bd7ed2a14f205345c84d6e1fa6

Comment: Apparently, webpack `v5`  has issues with some default settings. I came across simmilar issues before. There is a long long discussion here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11277#issuecomment-723476599. Try setting `devtool: 'source-map'`. If nothing else works, downgrade to `webpack@4`, that will definitely work.

Comment: Also, try rewriting `const useExternal = () => useState('external package');` as `function useExternal() { return useState('external package'); }`. That might fix the name mangling in `production`. `Function.name` working correctly for `ArrowFunctionExpression` is a rather new concept. Not sure if `webpack` got it right.

Comment: @Domi Thanks for all the help! I tried downgrading to version 4, still with no success :/ When running the development build I'm back at `Invalid hook call`.. Is there perhaps a better tool to use for this purpose? I'm considering Rollup as I saw that that is what Apollo Client is using..

Comment: Finally! It was a stupid mistake! To make it easier for me I stopped publishing packages to GitHub packages and instead installed the dependency locally with `fille:../Client`, I guess that is actually a symlink or similar and that is using the local to the Client node_module for React, causing duplicate instances of React. When I updated the package after properly defining the externals it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the help!

The issue was that I stopped publishing packages and instead installed the dependency locally using `file:../Client`. That caused duplicate instances of `React` since it used the local-to-the-Client-package instance of `React`. Publishing only the built output and then installing that dependency solved the issue for me.

I found the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259365/1219158) helpful for me to realize this (linking the react dependency between the two packages) if anyone else stumbles upon this.